# Textbox to populate base on DropDownList selection using sql on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have already created tables for officers profile. I want my `DropDownList` selected value to populate my 2 `Textboxes`. However, only the `DropDownList` have the database items but when I choose an item, the 2 `Textboxes` doesn't populate anything. I am using ASP.NET C# and SQL Management Studio. I would be happy if anyone could help and if there is a need to include query in the databases please teach me. Thx!!

Here are my codes for pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlName1.Items.Add(new ListItem("-Select Officer-", ""));
        ddlName1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        SqlConnection connName1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(...);" + "Initial Catalog=(...); Integrated Security=SSPI");
        connName1.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapName1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OfficersProfile", connName1);
        DataSet dsName1 = new DataSet();
        adapName1.Fill(dsName1);
        ddlName1.DataSource = dsName1;
        ddlName1.DataTextField = "officer_name";
        ddlName1.DataValueField = "officer_id";
        ddlName1.DataBind();

        connName1.Close();
    }

}
```

Here are my codes for selectedindexchanged

```
protected void ddlName1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connName1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(...);" + "Initial Catalog=(...); Integrated Security=SSPI");
    connName1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdName1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM OfficersProfile where officer_id=@officerID", connName1);
    cmdName1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@officerID", ddlName1.SelectedValue);
    SqlDataReader drName1;
    drName1 = cmdName1.ExecuteReader();
    while(drName1.Read())
    {
        txtDivision.Text = drName1[3].ToString();
        txtLSOExec.Text = drName1[4].ToString();
    }
    drName1.Close();
    connName1.Close();
}
```

Comment: PostBack is set to true ?? Exactly what is the problem you facing ? , error or no response ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `AutoPostBack="true"` in your DropDownList